# How do I make Emacs' other-window command ignore terminal windows?

Tags: emacs

Emacs does an okay job of being a window manager. I've been splitting up my Emacs frame like this:

```
+---------------------------+
|             |             |
|             |             |
|             |      B      |
|      A      |             |
|             |             |
|             |             |
|             |-------------|
|             |      C      |
+---------------------------+
```

`C` is usually a terminal with some kind of long-running process, like a web server or daemon. Occasionally I'll move the point there to restart the daemon, but most of the time I'd like to swap only between `A` and `B`. How can I make this convenient?

Comment: See useful function `esc-toggle-window-selectability` http://ericscrosson.wordpress.com/2013/04/27/ignoring-windows-with-other-window/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's nothing built-in to do what you want.  You can use the following code to do what you want (just customize the regular expression to match the name of the buffer(s) you want to avoid).

Note: the `my-other-window` doesn't implement all the features `other-window` does, that is left as an exercise for the reader.

`my-other-window` will try to switch to a window whose buffer doesn't match the `avoid-window-regexp`.  If there's no such window available, then it just switches to the next one.

```
(require 'cl)
(defvar avoid-window-regexp "^[0-9]$")
(defun my-other-window ()
  "Similar to 'other-window, only try to avoid windows whose buffers match avoid-window-regexp"
  (interactive)
  (let* ((window-list (delq (selected-window) (window-list)))
         (filtered-window-list (remove-if
                                (lambda (w)
                                  (string-match-p avoid-window-regexp (buffer-name (window-buffer w))))
                                window-list)))
    (if filtered-window-list
        (select-window (car filtered-window-list))
      (and window-list
           (select-window (car window-list))))))
```

And bind it appropriately:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x o") 'my-other-window)
```

Comment: FWIW, still using this regularly. Awesome.

Answer (score 2):

This works for eshell:

`(add-hook 'eshell-mode-hook (lambda ()
                         (set-window-parameter (first (window-list)) 'no-other-window t)))`

Setting no-other-window to non-nil makes the standard other-window function skip this. See other-window docs with `C-h C-f other-window`

There might be a better way to get the current window, but I don't know it yet.

Answer (score 0):

Not the exact answer but I use [windmove-mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/WindMove) for that which allow you to use the arrow to visually move between windows and then doing Control-Left or Control-Right to move only between A and B.

Other than that you probably can redefine other-buffer function with something that take buffer-list ignoring some patters when switch-to-buffer to it but I didn't write the code handy.

Comment: Yeah, I use this, but hitting one key instead of remembering a direction seems much more convenient. Thanks, though!

Comment: there is windows numbering mode by the way as well http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/window-number.el just another option, probably not answering your question tho.

Comment: ace-window allows quick switching to windows, like ace-jump allows quick switching to any word in any window. see avy-goto-line for similar switching tricks, which works across windows, aswell. https://github.com/abo-abo/ace-window https://github.com/winterTTr/ace-jump-mode https://github.com/abo-abo/avy

Answer (score -1):

For the lazy, I use something like this in my .emacs

```
(fset 'doublejump
      "\C-u2\C-xo")
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c o") 'doublejump)
```

and alternate between using single and double buffer switches.

Comment: I'm not sure how this is being lazy since it requires you to keep track of where you are in the buffer cycling and hit an alternate key. The point of the question (and the way to be lazy) is to ignore certain windows which @trey-jackson does in his answer.